# Python script fails to import mysql.connector when run from Lua

Tags: python, lua, mysql-connector, openresty

I have a Python script that I try to run from Openresty/Lua with the following Nginx location block:

```
location / {
    access_by_lua_block {
    ngx.req.read_body()
    local request = ngx.req.get_body_data()
    io.popen("python3 /www/test.py '" .. request .. "'")
        }
}
```

Script content:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import json
(...)
```

-- Run from command line => works

-- Run from Lua => works

But if I try to import mysql.connector it no longer works from Lua, although it still does from the command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import json
import mysql.connector
(...)
```

-- Run from command line => works

-- Run from Lua => fails / log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014947/mysql-connector-python-importerror-no-module-named-mysql

should `apt-get install python3-mysql.connector`
(i.e. not just `pip install mysql-connector-python3`)